# Code looking for files, how to modify it for directories and specific files

Tags: macos, zsh

Please anyone can explain how this code works so I can try to use it for directories, specific files etc. Thank you.

The point of that code is to read all files from old archive drives, to stretch their legs and find out if they have I/o errors and at what file. It copies files to a temp file on a ram disk.

It works perfectly in zsh, but I don't know how and could not find information.

The trick here is `(./**/*(.NDoN))`
That is where are the parameters about the files to gather.
In this case it takes all files, recursive, and not directories.
What if I want only directories, non recursive?
All files but non recursive, maxdepth 1?

```
#!/bin/zsh
cd /path_to_target
counter=1
for f (./**/*(.NDoN)) {echo " Reading file $counter : $f"; counter=$(($counter+1)); cp $f /Volumes/RAMDisk/tempp}
counter=$((counter-1))
echo $counter
```

The output looks like:

```
% counter=1; for f (./**/*(.NDoN)) { echo " Reading file $counter : $f"; counter=$[$counter+1]; cp $f /Volumes/RAMDisk/tempp }; counter=$((counter-1)); echo $counter
 Reading file 1 : ./20180317_171403.jpg
 Reading file 2 : ./20180317_171239.jpg
 Reading file 3 : ./20180317_171358.jpg
 Reading file 4 : ./20180317_171400.jpg
 Reading file 5 : ./20180317_171401.jpg
...
 Reading file 68120 : ./_backup/S500/iStuff/Photos Library/2016/09/05/_DSC3227.JPG
 Reading file 68121 : ./_backup/S500/iStuff/Photos Library./2016/09/05/_DSC3228.JPG
 ...
```

** I "suppose" means recursive,not sure. Tried only one * and it looks like files at the root are omitted, not what I want.

- is the wildcard. **/*.dng would return only dng files

I have no idea what `(.NDoN)` and how to manipulate it.
Trying to learn and understand.

Comment: Note also that decrementing the counter could have been written simpler as `((counter--))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ** I "suppose" means recursive,not sure. Tried only one * and it looks like files at the root are omitted, not what I want.

`**` means a chain of zero or more directories.  Perhaps that's also what you mean by "recursive".

A single `*` means zero or more characters, but not crossing directory boundaries.

> I have no idea what `(.NDoN)` and how to manipulate it. Trying to learn and understand.

That is a set of glob qualifiers.  I'm not sure whether there are any shells other than Zsh that recognize these, but certainly Bash and the POSIX shell do not.  There are several in that set:

- `.` indicating that only regular files should be matched (not directories, but also not symbolic links, named pipes, device files, or other special files)
- `N` indicating that the `NULL_GLOB` option should be enabled locally for that pattern.  The effect is that if the pattern does not match any files then it expands to nothing, instead of to the raw pattern itself.
- `D` indicating that the `GLOB_DOTS` option should be enabled locally for that pattern.  The effect is that wildcards will match a leading `.` in filenames (except in the special directory names `.` and `..`)
- `oN` indicating that the glob matches should not be sorted (**o**rder **N**one)

These are all described [in the Zsh documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

> What if I want only directories, non recursive?

All direct subdirectories of the current working directory, unsorted, including those whose names begin with a `.`, or nothing if there are no subdirectories: `*(/NDoN)`.  "Subdirectories" does not include `.` or `..`.

> All files but non recursive, maxdepth 1?

I'm not sure what you mean by combining "non recursive" with "maxdepth 1", nor am I certain whether by "all files" you mean all *regular* files.  All files other than `.` and `..` in the current working directory, including regular files, special files, *etc*., in the default order, would be `*(ND)`.